# Tangent space to the graph of a function

Tags: differential-topology

$X$ and $Y$ are smooth manifolds and let $f:X\to Y$ be a map. Let $\Gamma$ be the graph of $f$ in $X\times Y$. Prove that $T_{(x,y)}\Gamma$ is the graph of $df(x):T_xX\to T_yY$.

$\Gamma$ need not be a smooth manifold, does it? If it were I could parametrize it and define $T_{(x,y)}\Gamma$ to be the image of a parametrization. I don't know how this would help, though.

How do I prove this statement?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! If $\phi$ is a local chart for $X$, then $(\phi, f\circ \phi)$ is a local chart for the graph of $f$, so "yes", $\Gamma$ is a smooth manifold. How you proceed may depend on your definition (or favorite description) of the tangent space.

Comment: How is $(\phi, f\circ\phi)$ a local chart? What is the inverse map?

Comment: Projection on the first factor, $\pi_{1}:X \times Y \to X$, followed by $\phi^{-1}$. :)

Comment: Oh, yes, of course. Thank you!